# How did China stymie the Myanmar rebels before 2023?

Tags: china, civil-war, myanmar

[BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-67305690):

> Three ethnic insurgent armies in Shan State, supported by other armed groups opposing the government, have overrun dozens of military posts, and **captured border crossings and the roads carrying most of the overland trade with China**.
> The government has responded with airstrikes and artillery bombardments, forcing thousands of people to leave their homes. But it has been unable to bring in reinforcements or recover the ground it has lost.
>
> [...] crucially **China, which normally acts as a restraining influence on all the groups along its border with Myanmar, has not prevented this operation from going ahead**.

How did China stymie the rebels before 2023? I.e. what's changed now, on the ground at least in term of Chinese dispositions?

Comment: Are you asking what means China used to restrain the rebel groups, or why it's stopped restraining the rebel groups? I'm assuming it's the former, since the latter is answered in the next paragraph of the quoted article.

Comment: @F1Krazy: yes how not why. The 'why' is amply explained in the piece (if anybody wonders: China was pissed that the Myanmar gov't didn't do enough/anything against slavers holding scammers. And so China used the rebel groups as their external police, of sorts.)

Comment: How does "normally acts as a restraining influence on all the groups along its border" become "China stymie the Myanmar rebels"?

Comment: @user103496: well, feel free to explain how China acted as a "restraining influence" if that's your preferred wording.

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56435/has-china-been-funding-ethnic-militias-in-myanmar